# IOS magical record create new entity and add to array not woking

Tags: ios, entity, magicalrecord

Hi I'm working with Core Data and Magical Record. After receive JSON response from server. I want to create an entity, update its property and add to and array.

My code is

```
NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray array];
NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];
Article *article = [Article MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];
[article setOrderingValue:idx];
[article updateWithApiRepresentation:articleJSON];
[items addObject:article];
```

I dont know why the above is not working (does not return correct items array). It's only work if I replace this line

```
Article *article = [Article MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];
```

with this line

```
Article *article = [[Article alloc] initWithEntity:[Article entityInManagedObjectContext:localContext] insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
```

The main purpose is to return correct `items` array. Any help is much appreciate. Thanks

Comment: Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: HI there. how to create and update and add entity to array