# IOS coredata Magical record stupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

Hi I'm using magicalRecord to work with coredata.

I have added 1 more relationship to my coredata and use

```
[MagicalRecord setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack];
```

in may `appdelegate`
I have also made new xcdatamodeld base on old one

But when build and run again. not think change

My old coredata

[image]

My newone

[image]

I have add 1 more relationship for new one but in file `_Article.h` nothing change and i can not setup a relationship 
(for example `[article setArticleCategory)`)

Dont know why the migration not working. Any help is much appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add this code to your appdelegate :

```
[MagicalRecord setDefaultModelNamed:@"SingPost.momd"];
NSURL *myPath = [NSPersistentStore MR_defaultLocalStoreUrl];    
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreAtURL:myPath];
```

hope it work !!

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. It is in swift. I'm working in ObjectiveC now. One more prob is the default NSmanageObjectClass has change from _Article to Article+CoreDataProperties (when I try to create NSmanageObject class again)

Comment: Hi, done as your suggestion but still cannot set the relationship. Think problem is with my NSManageObjectSubClass. we need to generate the class again!

Comment: yeah maybe you need to delete all and recreate classes just try it !!

Comment: thanks. Will try create again. I have another question. It is much appreciate if you could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38762689/ios-magical-record-create-new-entity-and-add-to-array-not-woking